# phpseclib exceeded max execution time

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I am currently using laravel(which uses phpseclib) for my project and was having issues with the ssh connection, getting the error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` now I know this value can be extended but I should not have to in order to run a simple `ls` command.

it seems to be failing in this class `phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php`

I have tried every example in the [phpseclib documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html), I am still getting the same errors.

I have also tried using `exec("ssh -i /path/to/key user@host ls", $out, $code);` and **I am able to connect just fine.**

I have also testing `fsock` and no errors returned, so everything looks good.

```
  $fsock = fsockopen('server', 22);
  echo fgets($fsock, 1024);
```

any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Try to debug ssh by adding -v option.It will show something useful  `exec("ssh -v -i /path/to/key user@host ls", $out, $code); `

Comment: I am able to connect using that method... I cannot connecting using the phpseclib librarry

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, it turns out my openssl library version and header version did not match, this causes phpseclib to use a slower library, which then causes the timeout. as a temporary fix I have modified the following.

[here:](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php)

starting at line 256

from this :

```
       switch (true) {
            case !isset($versions['Header']):
            case !isset($versions['Library']):
            case $versions['Header'] == $versions['Library']:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED', true);
                break;
            default:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_DISABLE', true);
        }
```

to this:

```
      switch (true) {
            case !isset($versions['Header']):
            case !isset($versions['Library']):
            case $versions['Header'] == $versions['Library']:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED', true);
                break;
            default:
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLE', true);
        }
```

Comment: That was added because, when the OpenSSL versions don't match, OpenSSL can crash per http://stackoverflow.com/q/16628102/569976 . Can you post a copy of your phpinfo()? In particular, I'm wondering if (1) you're using internal mode and (2) if your ints are int64 per http://stackoverflow.com/a/23608651/569976 . Of course your timeout could be really low as well. Really, the best way to speed it up, per http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html would be to use gmp.

Comment: that commit did fix the issue, although it is still much slower than when I had OPenssl enabled.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. phpseclib uses the pure-PHP mode as an absolute last resort, when nothing else is available. Although that said since you're using Linux and it seems the OpenSSL crashing issue is only effecting XAMPP users maybe the phpseclib author could make it so that the check is only performed when the OS is Windows idk.